# How do I get google maps to render using google-maps-react module?

Tags: google-maps, reactjs

I'm having an issue with rendering the map when I'm passing the map to an export component... nothing will show up on the page.

I do get the loading map status but then nothing happens afterwards. Please help!! Any answer will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this actually.

In your Map component you need to include a style tag.

```
    const style = {
        width: '100vw',
        height: '100vh'
    }
```

and include it in your map div

```
    return (
          <div ref='map' style={style}>
            Loading..
          </div>
        )
```

Let me know if it works for you!